# Getting Nodes from Drools-Guvnor

Tags: drools, jbpm, drools-guvnor

I am using Jbpm 5.4. I have created my workflows in Drools guvnor. I want to get node details about work flow before starting the workflow. Is there any way to do that? Any suggestions?

I found the solution as follows;

```
org.drools.definition.process.Process process=kbase.getProcess("defaultPackage.org.Task");
NodeContainer container = (NodeContainer) process;  
Node[] nodes=container.getNodes();
for(Node node:nodes){
out.println("This is a Human Task"+node.getName());
out.println("This is a Human Task"+node.getMetaData());
Map<String, Object> map=node.getMetaData();
for(String key : map.keySet()){
out.println("key:::"+key +"value::"+map.get(key));
}}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what kind of details you are looking for?  Also, when you mention "before starting the workflow" do you mean for the first time or restarting it?

Comment: I want to get node names from the workflow before calling ksession.StartProcess() method.